# Как достать из текст из текстового файла и поместить его в массив

Tags: php

есть текстовый файл 
    `<tag k="addr:housenumber" v="11 к1"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Крякова Улица"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="11 к1"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="АКА Улица"/>`

надо отсюда вытащить улицы и дома в массив много таких текстов в файле много разного но улицы и дома везде похожи как это всё можно сделать в цикле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подойдут регулярки, то можно так:

```
$str = '<tag k="addr:housenumber" v="11 к1"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Крякова Улица"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="11 к1"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="АКА Улица"/>';

$patt = '~<tag k="addr:(?:housenumber|street)" v="\K[^"]+~';
$arr = preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr) ? $arr[0] : [];
$arr = array_chunk($arr, 2); // Если не нужно разбивать массив, закомментить эту строку

var_dump($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '11 к1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Крякова Улица' (length=25)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '11 к1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'АКА Улица' (length=17)
```

При необходимости полученный массив можно разбить на части: `$arr = array_chunk($arr, 2);`

Comment: Как можно достать файлы только с k="addr:housenumber"  И  k="addr:street" а то у меня под эту регулярку попадают и другие текста

Comment: @Gradusnik я обновил ответ.